# Typeof in V8 engine

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, v8, chromium

I am experimentation with V8 engine, i am not a C programmer and it is very difficult for me .But i need this thing for myself

I change a function **RUNTIME_FUNCTION(Runtime_Typeof)**; (runtime-object.cc)
And now if to create proxy in JS:

```
prx = Proxy.create({
 get:function(k,v){
    if( v == '%type_of%'){
       return 'string'
    }
    .......
 }
})

typeof prx  -> "string"
```

Ok, i want this effect

BUT if try to make compare:

```
  typeof prx == 'string' -> false =(
  typeof prx == 'object' -> true
  (x = typeof prx) == 'string' -> true
```

After many hours i found this:
In V8  (**full-codegen-x64.cc**) exist this func  void   **FullCodeGenerator**::**EmitLiteralCompareTypeof**

It is look like an optimizator for expression

```
   typeof prx == "string" || "number" || "object" and etc..
   if (String::Equals(check, factory->number_string())) {
   ...
   } else if (String::Equals(check, factory->string_string())) {
   and etc...
```

it do not call **Runtime_Typeof** and

```
    typeof prx -> "string"
    typeof prx == 'string' -> false =(
```

How can i check if **typeof prx** it is proxy, then v8 must to call **Runtime_Typeof**..

if   `typeof prx -> string,   then typeof == 'string' must be true!` 
Help me please

Answer (score 1):

You would need to *emit code* that distinguishes the cases *at runtime*. That is not too hard, but not a completely trivial change either. Moreover, you'd also need to adapt the optimising compiler.

But that's the easy part. Changing the meaning of typeof will break other parts of the system, which rely on the correct semantics. For example, all uses of the IS_STRING primitive in V8's built-in libraries will become incorrect -- you are likely to introduce crashes that way.

Even if you managed to fix all that, the idea would be very questionable from a language semantics perspective. There is a reason why proxies cannot fake strings, first and foremost, strings aren't objects. You would also break JavaScript code that relies on the spec'ed behaviour.

In short: **don't**. It's a really bad idea.

Comment: Yes, i know that it is bad idea, because Proxy must be an object
On the other hand, When i changed Runtime_Typeof and compile ..
it work correctly
In fact i cant understand what's happening here ..
**void FullCodeGenerator::EmitLiteralCompareTypeof( expr,sub_expr,<String> check)**

**sub_expr -> it is my [typeof prx]**

**{ AccumulatorValueContext context(this);
    VisitForTypeofValue(sub_expr);**   _<- wtf?  it is mean that v8 check typeof?_
**}**

Comment: The fact that it compiled and didn't crash immediately doesn't mean that it worked "correctly". I could probably produce a program that crashes under that change with not much effort. (I'm not sure what specifically your question is above, but it generates code specialised for the case for the RHS is a string literal.)

Comment: Andreas Rossberg, about  crash you right
thank you very much, but i really need it :\

Comment: Andreas thanks for help, please if you know something about v8, maybe you can tell me : it  is possible to get JSObject from Expresison* in v8
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102874/v8-how-to-get-jsobject-from-expression