# Typeof and Expression* in V8

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, v8, chromium

I am experimenting with the V8 engine.

In V8 (full-codegen-x64.cc) exists this function for comparing types:

```
void FullCodeGenerator::EmitLiteralCompareTypeof(Expression* expr,
                                             Expression* sub_expr,
                                             Handle<String> check)
```

So, if for example:

```
   typeof Obj == "object"
```

Then **sub_expr** is an **Expression object** with **"typeof Obj"** and **check** is an **"object"**.

**<strike>How can I get a JSObject from an Expression object, if possible?</strike>** - not possible (You can't. An Expression is a piece of syntax Andreas Rossberg)

In void [FullCodeGenerator::EmitLiteralCompareTypeof](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/v8/src/x64/full-codegen-x64.cc&q=FullCodeGenerator::EmitLiteralCompareTypeof&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=5030) we can check if :

```
Obj is function   __ CmpObjectType(rax, JS_FUNCTION_TYPE, rdx);
Obj is proxy function  __ CmpInstanceType(rdx, JS_FUNCTION_PROXY_TYPE);
Obj is proxy __ CmpObjectType(rax, FIRST_NONCALLABLE_SPEC_OBJECT_TYPE, rdx);
and etc...
```

Just for example if we will use this code:

```
__ CmpObjectType(rax, FIRST_NONCALLABLE_SPEC_OBJECT_TYPE, rdx);
__ j(equal, if_true);
then
typeof Proxy_Obj == 'string'  ---> true
```

**How V8 knows about this? Is it mean - V8 run code?**

Comment: Can you describe what actual problem you want to solve? I understand that the function you've shown here is part of the V8 engine itself. Are you writing an extension that needs to do something similar? What is the actual code that needs to perform this conversion?

Comment: Thanks Austin. Yes I wrote  extension for myself.
And I have a problem.
So  i need to get JSObject in V8 (here full-codegen-x64.cc). And I know -  Expression* sub_expr-> it is part of code "typeof OBJ", but I dont know How to get JSObject here =\
Here is an api (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/v8/src/ast.h&q=Expressio&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=332) but I cant to find nothing about

Comment: Well, I don't know the solution exactly, but my approach would be to first verify that `sub_expr` is a `UnaryOperation`. If so, cast it as one, then get its `expression` member. Then verify the `expression` is a `VariableProxy`, then `Variable`. I think that's as far as you can go without accessing the actual run-time memory. There doesn't seem to be any memory context passed into this function, though.

Comment: Austin, you absolutely right
I can do this:
`Variable* var = sub_expr->AsVariableProxy()->var();`
And here I can found **Variable class** (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/v8/src/variables.h&q=Variabl&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=19)
But JSObject::cast do not work =\

In fact I need to get `typeof Var` -> as String...object,function and etc
And I think - is it possible "execute"  sub_expr  maybe and to get result?

Comment: I don't have any idea. It seems like that would only be possible at run time, and this is part of compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. An Expression is a piece of syntax, a JSObject is a runtime object. They have absolutely nothing to do with each other.